# Join two tables with different column names and same rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table1:

```
|age  | name   | sex  | money |
-------------------------------
|20   | James  | 1    | 1000  |
|20   | Marry  | 2    | 2000  |
|20   | Kate   | 2    | 1500  |
|20   | Parker | 1    | 1800  |
```

And I have two query results:

1:

```
select `age`, count(*) as `man`, sum(money) as man_money
from table1
where `sex` = 1 and age = 20;

|age| man   | man_money |
-------------------------
|20 | 2     | 2800      |
```

2:

```
select `age`, count(*) as `woman`, sum(money) as woman_money
from table1
where `sex` = 2 and age = 20;

|age |woman   | woman_money |
-----------------------------
|20  |2       | 3500        |
```

I want to combine the results like:

```
|age | man   | woman  | man_money | woman_money |
--------------------------------------------------
|20  | 2     | 2      | 2800      | 3500        |
```

How to write the SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select age, 
       count(case when sex = 1 then 1 end) as man,
       count(case when sex = 2 then 1 end) as woman,
       sum(case when sex = 1 then money end) as man_money,
       sum(case when sex = 2 then money end) as woman_money
from table1
where age = 20
```

Comment: thanks, this works~  but is there any way to join two result directly?  because some columns need to use SUM() method

Comment: @teejoe You mean join the two queries of the question as they are?

Comment: ***@teejoe***: you can also use *`case`* in multiple times in a query and can combine with *`sum`* ...

Comment: I suppose you are referring with the age column? Because it does not consist of aggregate functions. You can just add `Group by Age`

Comment: or, as this appears to be MySQL, just `SUM(sex=1)`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about Mysql, but as my knowledge sql is same for all DB, I tried this in oracle it works as you need

```
select age, 

       count(case when sex = 1 then 1 end) as man,

       count(case when sex = 2 then 1 end) as woman

from table1 group by age;
```